# Как сделать проверку на != 0 у переменной

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**У меня имеется такая ссылка**

```js
        <Link to={`/name/${area.id}/${item.id}`} className="order">
          Оформить заказ ({price})
</Link>
```

**И такой код который генерирует выводимую переменную**

```js
  const [ price, products ] = useMemo(() => {
    const foodIds = new Set((item.foods || []).map(item => item.id));

    const products = Object.values(order)
      .filter((value) => {
        const { item: { id }} = value;

        return foodIds.has(id);
      });

    const result = products.reduce((result, value) => {
        const { count, item } = value;

        return result + parseInt(item.price) * parseInt(count);
      }, 0);

    return [ accounting.formatNumber(result, 0, ' '), products ];
  }, [ order, item ]);
```

Сам вопрос в том как можно сделать проверку price !== 0 и если равно то выводить ошибку, пробовал проверять переменную внутри функции, но ничего не вышло

Comment: `return price <= 0 ? <EmptyCartMessage/> :`, или в чем вопрос?

Answer (score -1):

может быть, можно сделать проверку price !== 0 вне функции:

```
const [ price, products ]= {
    ...
    return [ result, products ];
...
if(0 === price) throw...
price = accounting.formatNumber(price, 0, ' ');
```

Comment: == сравнение с приведением типов, надо использовать ===, т.к. будет выполняться условие 'false' или unindefined

Comment: в твоем случае полностью крашится приложение когда я убираю все товары так как переменная price = 0

Comment: @xydope Спасибо, я исправил

Comment: @Andrey Freiz Проверка, содержит ли коллекция какое-либо значение, не входила в вопрос. Проверка того, содержит ли коллекция какое-либо значение, не входила в вопрос. Вы должны добавить еще один чек для этого.